# Google Groups Authentication

Tags: authentication, authorization, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm aware that there is not an API for Google groups (yet). However, I'm trying to use Google groups mobile in a web view within an app where we access other Google services as well, most specifically Google docs.

Login is done by accessing the [Google service login](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin) which returns a token that you can use in subsequent request in the HTTP header to get authenticated access. This works perfectly for the Google docs service by supplying the Google docs [serviceID](http://code.google.com/apis/base/faq_gdata.html#clientlogin).

Unfortunately this does not work for Google groups because there is no serviceID published for this service. Is there any other way to supply a token to Google groups to bypass the login screen and cause the user to be authenticated or is there a hidden serviceID for Google groups that can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: I found out that "groups2" is the serviceID for Google groups, however supplying the auth token retrieved with this serviceID only works partially because of the Javascript used to load the actual group page. It hangs in the Loading state.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm in the same situation